# unknown property 'LibraryVariants' in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I have the error below in build.gradle at this line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

> Error:(56, 0) Could not get unknown property 'LibraryVariants' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

It happened after I installed Firebase.

How to solve this?

Comment: please show here root Project gradle and app level gradle

Comment: Same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44229961/unknown-libraryvariants-property-gradle-will-not-sync and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45092308/failed-to-apply-plugin-com-google-gms-google-services (the latter has a solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to the @project level gradle file:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Add the following to the @app level gradle file:

```
// Dependency for Google Sign-In
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
```

Apply plugin

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I have         `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'`
        `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'` at project level, `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.2.0'` and `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at module level, and still have that error. Could you help?

Comment: @EvgeniyPhilippov did you get any solution? because I'm having same problem.

Answer (score 9):

The error message, **Error: Could not get unknown property 'LibraryVariants' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension**, indicates that this plugin needs to be applied to a module which uses the `com.android.application` plugin.

So, the simple solution is to only include the google-services plugin in your application module and *not* your library module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and solved it updating gradle and google-services versions.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Google's gcm site listed `com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0` as the required version, but 3.1.1 is when it is fixed. It also required that `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` was posted AFTER the compile for auth.