# Gradle failes to sync and/or assemble library project when I add google services plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I want to add Firebase Auth functionality to my Unity Android plugin, so
I followed [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and added

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

to app's build.gradle file. But sync started to fail with

```
Error:(40, 0) Could not get unknown property 'LibraryVariants' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.
```

Here is a complete build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        project.archivesBaseName = "AndroidPlugin"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def outputFile = output.outputFile
            if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('release.aar')) {
                def fileName = "${archivesBaseName}.aar"
                output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
            }
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    provided fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile "com.android.support:exifinterface:25.3.1"
    compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's the same as this guy problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44884400/unknown-property-libraryvariants-in-build-gradle

Comment: @RootOnChair, yeah, looks similar, but I already have accepted answer in my gradle files

Answer (score 0):

You try add to project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Yes, my project build.gradle looks identically except versions and additional repository. Added.