# Error when putting google service plugin in library module

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-library, google-cloud-firestore

when I place the

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

in library module in app level it show an error like

> 'Could not get unknown property 'LibraryVariants' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension'

So I removed the plugin it build successfully. But the data is not store in FireStore. How can I store the data when I place the plugin in library module.

How to solve that problem ?
Root level app module  :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.vijayasrivudanti.pages"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:4.1.5'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':pays')


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


Library app module :

   // enter code here
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:4.1.5'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.4.2'

    //compile project(':ReactAndroid')
    //compile (project(':react-native-firestack')){exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: hope you written apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' after all dependencies. at the end of gradle file

Comment: yes I added. I am asking about library app:module in that I am facing that error..

Comment: Have u added the google services in the root leve buil.gradle?

Comment: Ya I added plugin in root level too @ Niraj

Comment: @LahariAreti can you post your app gradle and module gradle

Comment: @LahariAreti see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44884400/unknown-property-libraryvariants-in-build-gradle

Comment: I have already seen that link @Vishal Thakkar

Comment: why you write twice all lib dependencies in app and project gradle? check you posted both app gradle i think

Comment: one is for Mainapp gradle and second one is library level app module

Answer (score 1):

Add the below in your root build.gradle file

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

In a library module, you do not need to add the plugin; you can directly use the compile repo of Google services. Just make sure it is there in app level build.gradle file.

Below is a sample whole file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

here is a sample app level build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash'
android {

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ncommunity.agriculture"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.10"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            resValue("string", "PORT_NUMBER", "8081")
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    debugCompile project(':debug-db')
    compile project(':tracker')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.shadow-layout:library:1.0.3'
   /* compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'*/
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.Kunzisoft:Android-SwitchDateTimePicker:1.7'
    compile 'com.github.safetysystemtechnology:location-tracker-background:v1.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: If I remove the plugin in library module .. Then the data is stored in the main level app database. But for me the data should store in the library level database

Comment: Can u clarify on App Database?

Comment: I need to store data on firestore maintained by some other user, but unfortunately it is storing in my database itself.

Comment: I am facing an error during integration.Although the individual apps works fine.

Comment: when u build the Google client u need to put up details correctly, make up different methods for same, and call appropriately before that.

Comment: What, be more specific please

Comment: When u initialize the google client u must use different credentials