# Failed to apply plugin "com.google.gms.google-services"

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Here is my project **build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}
```

In one of the module's **build.gradle** I have this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

which results into the following error:

```
Could not get unknown property 'LibraryVariants' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.
```

Fun fact, if I set `google-services` version to `3.0.0`, this specific error disappears, but Gradle asks me to downgrade versions of other google libraries, but I really do not want to do that.

How do I deal with these `LibraryVariants`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only set `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in the **app** module, and in no other modules.

Comment: thank you, @Muz for your short and clarify the answer

Answer (score 1):

You must add one dependencies in your **build.gradle(Project:project_name)**

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

And add in your **build.gradle(build.gradle:Module app)**

> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

```
dependencies {

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

 }
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```