# How to initialize Firebase Cloud Messaging in a lower library?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I moved Firebase Cloud Messaging to a library, so that I can import this into any of my apps and provide push messages. So therefore I created a library and moved everything [from this example](https://www.codementor.io/flame3/send-push-notifications-to-android-with-firebase-du10860kb) to my library.

Then I compile this library in my `build.gradle` and use it as desired.
This works so far when I instantiate Firebase from app level:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(topic)
```

Now, I thought of moving this down into my library:

```
fun initFirebaseMessaging(topic : String) : String
{
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(topic)
    Timber.d("Push subscribeToTopic $topic")
    val token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().token!!
    Timber.d("Push FirebaseinstanceId token $token")
    sendRegistrationToServer(token)
    return token
}
```

Since I do not hand over the app level context, I get:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.demo, PID: 8047
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demo/com.example.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.demo. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.demo. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source:58)
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                   at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.getInstance(Unknown Source:9)
                                                                   at com.example.network.fcm.exampleFirebaseInstanceIdService$Companion.initFirebaseMessaging(exampleFirebaseInstanceIdService.kt:14)
                                                                   at com.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:168)
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

ADDENDUM: I added that line to my init

```
fun initFirebaseMessaging(topic : String, context : context) : String
{
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context)
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(topic)
    Timber.d("Push subscribeToTopic $topic")
    val token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().token!!
    Timber.d("Push FirebaseinstanceId token $token")
    sendRegistrationToServer(token)
    return token
}
```

leads to very same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error

```
Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
```

In your library u need create function like

```
public static void Init(Context context) {
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context);
}
```

and call it before using firebase. Best way its add to your application
example :

```
... extends Application /*** code **/ 
onCreate () { 
YourLibrary.Init(this);
}
```

Comment: See in the addendum field above, it leads to same error message

Comment: do u google-json file ?
do u have in build gradle  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' ?

Comment: According to a comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44229961/unknown-libraryvariants-property-gradle-will-not-sync I am able to use apply plugin in the app level only, and not in the lib level?